# Apache Spark Dataframe replacing null values only in one column instead of doing it for all columns

Tags: python, apache-spark

**Question**: Why the following code is replacing null values only on the first column with null values and not the other columns that also have null values? For example if column1 and column2 have no null values, and column3, column6, column9 have null values, it will only replace null values in column3 but not in column6 and column9. How can we resolve the issue? Note: All columns are of string type. And I am using 'Python`and`not` scala.

**Details**: I'm using [Apache Spark Connector for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15). Reading `csv` file to a `Spark dataframe` works fine but when importing that dataframe to a SQL server table it, only first column with null values gets its null values replaced by an empty string. csv file has about 50 column many of them have some null values.

**Remarks**: I do not want to use optional parameter `subset` where you define a subset of columns since there are more than 50 columns and many tables that I need to work on.

```
df = spark.read.csv("...../Test/MyFile.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

df1 = df.fillna("")

server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER_ADDR}"
    database_name = "database_name"
    url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"
    
    table_name = "table_name"
    username = "username"
    password = "password123!#"
    
    try:
      df1.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .save()
    except ValueError as error :
        print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Answer (score 0):

the Fillna function depends on the schema of your underlying dataset.

As the document states - fillna(value, subset=None)

value must be a mapping from column name (string) to replacement value. The replacement value must be an int, float, boolean, or string.

Below is an exmaple to demonstrate the same

**Data Preparation**

```
input_str = """
|1  |704    |STANDARD|null               |PR   |30100
|2  |null    |null    |PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|PR   |null
|3  |709    |null    |BDA SAN LUIS       |PR   |3700
|4  |null  |UNIQUE  |CINGULAR WIRELESS  |TX   |84000
|5  |76177  |STANDARD|null               |TX   |null
""".split("|")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else 
None, input_str[1:]))

n = len(input_values)

cols = ['id','zipcode','type','city','state','population']

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+6]) for i in range(0,n,6)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|zipcode|    type|               city|state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|  1|    704|STANDARD|               null|   PR|     30100|
|  2|   null|    null|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|      null|
|  3|    709|    null|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|      3700|
|  4|   null|  UNIQUE|  CINGULAR WIRELESS|   TX|     84000|
|  5|  76177|STANDARD|               null|   TX|      null|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+

root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- zipcode: string (nullable = true)
|-- type: string (nullable = true)
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- state: string (nullable = true)
|-- population: string (nullable = true)
```

**FillNa**

FillNa directly without casting , as the schema is string , would replaces all the null values to ***

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.na.fill('****')

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|zipcode|    type|               city|state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|  1|    704|STANDARD|               ****|   PR|     30100| 
|  2|   ****|    ****|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|      ****|
|  3|    709|    ****|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|      3700|
|  4|   ****|  UNIQUE|  CINGULAR WIRELESS|   TX|     84000|
|  5|  76177|STANDARD|               ****|   TX|      ****|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
```

**Casting & FillNa**

Casting population and id to DoubleType , and filling with 0 populates the null values within the DoubleType columns to 0

```
sparkDF =sparkDF.withColumn('zipcode',F.col('zipcode').cast(DoubleType()))\
             
.withColumn('population',F.col('population').cast(DoubleType()))

sparkDF = sparkDF.na.fill(0)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+ 
| id|zipcode|    type|               city|state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|  1|  704.0|STANDARD|               null|   PR|   30100.0|
|  2|    0.0|    null|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|       0.0|
|  3|  709.0|    null|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|    3700.0|
|  4|    0.0|  UNIQUE|  CINGULAR WIRELESS|   TX|   84000.0|
|  5|76177.0|STANDARD|               null|   TX|       0.0|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
```